python - can't open directory /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin
Hello everyone i've a Mac Book pro M3 and I need to open an HDF5 dataset in python, here is my code:
import h5py
import hdf5plugin

file_path = './blink.hdf5'

with h5py.File(file_path, 'r+') as h5_file:
    evts = h5_file["CD"]["events"]
    print(len(evts[(evts['t']<49330) & (evts['t']>48270) & (evts['x']<300) & (evts['y']>300)]))

    h5_file.close()


i've installed both h5py and hdf5plugin but unfortunately I get an error:
OSError: Can't read data (can't open directory: /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin)
I've already tried to set the enviroment variables, in zshrc file but i can't solve the issue.

Either you do not have permissions to the file, or it is nonexistent. What is the output of cat /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin?

the directory does not exists, but if is not sufficient to install hdf5plugin to get it work?

I don't understand...try creating the file: touch blind.hdf5. I have never worked with hdf5 so I don't know whether that is enough...i doubt it. hopefully someone else with more experience with this library will answer you.

It's possible pip is using a different Python interpreter (other than the system Python on your Mac)

Also, it's not the HDF5 file that your system can't find, it's the plugin

https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/cant-open-directory-usr-local-hdf5-lib-plugin/9738 according to this i've to set the environment variable or install hdf5plugin in python, the problem is where is the location of hdf5_plugin directory? in hdf5 installation directory i don't have a plugin directory.

i've checked, the interpreter is correct, unfortunately.

After opening, try to print the dataset compression attribute print(evts.compression). Also check the dataset fields: print(evts.dtype). Note: when you use the with/as context manager, to the file object is automatically closed when you exit that code block. Don't close it inside the block.

I think that the problem is about my processor architecture, I have Apple silicon M3 it's an arm64 processor. Does someone know how I can use h5py on my computer? Oh window is working perfectly.
